# Android Developing - Users Wallpaper as App Background

Tags: android, background, wallpaper, homescreen

Is it possible to somehow set the users home-screen wallpaper as the background of an Android app?  I think it could be a very interesting way of making your app seem to be more of a part of the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this, but you may be able to use a [WindowManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html), and then use `public static final int FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER`.

From WindowManager docs  `Window flag: ask that the system wallpaper be shown behind your window. The window surface must be translucent to be able to actually see the wallpaper behind it; this flag just ensures that the wallpaper surface will be there if this window actually has translucent regions.`

You can set your window area to transparent above this and that may solve your issue. It's a clever idea, and I'd love to see how it turns out.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? Or did you just abandon it?